# Как сделать такой прозрачный текст?

Tags: css, вёрстка

каким образом можно сделать такой цвет. Text shadow не справляется

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0A0718, #CA2738);
  padding: 20px;
}
span {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px #fff;
  color: #0A0718;
}
@supports (-webkit-text-stroke: 1px white) {
  span {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<span>PRICE</span>
```